# About URL redirect for Internet Explorer on desktop

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, url, plugins, bho

I need a plug-in which can implement some certain **customized URL redirection** for **Internet Explorer** on my **Windows desktop**.

For example, when I use Internet Explorer to click a new link http://sviehb.wordpress.com/, I hope my IE can automatically redirect the link to https://sviehb.wordpress.com/. Therefore, the first function for this plug-in should be **automatic redirection**.

And the second function of this plug-in should support **regular expressions**. For example, if I hope that all subdomains of **http://*.wordpress.com/** (where the symbol * is wildcard character) can be redirected to **https://*.wordpress.com/**, then regular expressions is very convenient for customizations!

Next, there are some extra restrictions for the implement of this plug-in. Firstly, if possible, the plug-in is not rely on any huge environments such as **.NET Framework**, **Perl** and **JRE**, namely, users of this plug-in do not need to install theses runtime environments on their computers! Secondly, do not use **privoxy** or **proxomitron** as implement, since their efficiency is not very good. Thirdly, this implement is just for Internet Explorer, so do not sacrifice efficiency to satisfy portability.

There are many similar implements in Firefox with Greasemonkey. But I have not found an implement for IE! Therefore, if you know an implement which satisfy the two functions and three restrictions referred above, please tell me. If there is not an implement like this, then I am waitting for your simple, elegant and efficient solution!

Finally, I hope that the implement is executable, certainly, better with source codes. I think that using **BHO**(Browser Helper Object) is a possible choice.

Comment: maybe better suited to  ask at superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is implementing a custom **Asynchronous Pluggable Protocols**. In Internet explorer, all protocols (e.g. http:, https:, file:, about:, mail:, etc.) are pluggable. These are COM objects which implement the IInternetProtocol interface (and few more).
The pluggable protocol architecture supports redirection, so you can implement one protocol using another one. You will override the 'http:' protocol and redirect it to https according to your requirement.
Not the easiest task but doable in few days.

Check out the link before for overview, reference and tutorial:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767916(v=VS.85).aspx